# How to hide the name of the web page using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to hide the name of the web page in the URL after the application of a redirect rule:

These are the contents of my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^192\.168\.199\.129$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/index2.html$ [NC]
RewriteRule ./* http://multiserver.example.com/user1/index2.html [R=301,L]
```

The above rule lets me redirect a user with particular ip to the page I want, but after that I also want to hide the name of the new web page( here it is index2.html) in the user's browser address bar such that the URL being displayed becomes multiserver.example.com/user1/.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a browser redirect (`[R=301]`), use the internal proxy flag: `[P]`

```
RewriteRule ./* http://multiserver.example.com/user1/index2.html [P,L]
```

This way, the browser's address bar doesn't change because it doesn't get a 301 response from the server.

Comment: Now it's keeping the URL same but it's not redirecting to index2.html anymore. It's giving a NOT FOUND error :-(

Comment: Can anyone please help me on this issue??

Comment: I don't know why changing the `R=301` to `P` isn't working. The URL hasn't changed.

Comment: No, I do want to change the URL. It should redirect the user from user1/index.html to user1/index2.html but should not show this change in the browser's address bar. It should show the same http://multiserver.example.com/user1/  in the browser's address bar.